# Are there any issues with approving pull requests out of chronological sequence?

Tags: github, azure-devops

I have a set of pull requests like this in

- Unrelated changes Aug 1, 2022
- Other stuff July 31, 2022
- New code July 15, 2022

The first pull request doesn't involve any code that is touched by the other two pull requests.  If I approve the Aug 1 pull request first, will that negatively impact the other pull requests in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the changes are completely independent, no.

The extant pull requests may need to have conflicts resolved before they can be merged, however.